# Python run another script from a python script

Tags: python, python-2.7, command, os.system

```
def run_cmd(self, cmd):
    print cmd 

    status = os.system(cmd)
    print 'Command ran with Status: %s' % status

    if status:
        s = 'Command Failed: Status: %s for %s' % (status, cmd)
        print s
        sys.exit(status)
    else:
        s = 'Command Success: %s' % cmd 

    return status
```

I am using this function to run a python script from another script.

Ex:

```
command_to_exec = 'python script_b.py'
run_cmd(command_to_exec)
```

Now if script_b.py fails script_a.py exits with the status.

That's okay.

**Case 2**:

```
command_to_exec = 'python script_a.py --options'
rum_cmd(command_to_exec)
```

This case is script_a.py running 'python script_a.py' from itself.
In this case, if newly spawned script_a.py fails, the outer script_a.py is still a success, because it wasn't able to catch the failure of inner script_a.py (because of sys.exit(status))

Now, how do I handle this situation? (If inner script_a fails, outer script_a should exit)

Comment: Why are you calling whole scripts like this? Why not import the 'inner' script, or the parts of it you need, and run those?

Like why not call a function in the 'inner' script?

Comment: Use may use subprocess https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system

Comment: You could test `sys.argv[0]` to prevent running yourself, which could cause a horrible fork bomb (continually spawning process).

Answer (score 0):

You can just run your other script as a module. Let's say you have the folder:
dir
   |---main.py
   |---imported.py
And you want to run the second from the first. Just use `import`, like that:

```
import imported #the file name without the extension
```

It will run that file, and you will be able to use it's vars and functions in your main script.

Comment: It's not possible in my case because I have different options to give to the spawned script.